# 田中さんはこの小説を読んだ（そうだ）-　do we need そうだ all the time if we did not actuality get the info from the person?

Tags: usage

**Example 1**

> Me: 明日は先生が来る（そうだ）。

**Example 2**

> Me: 田中さんはこの小説を読んだ（そうだ）。

Assume both Examples 1 and 2 are the information I heard from other people, not from 田中さん or 先生.

Can I say the Examples without そうだ?

In what situation can I not use そうだ? If the sources of information are trustworthy?

Answer (score 2):

そうだ is a hearsay marker that roughly corresponds to "I heard" or "[They] said (to me)". It's useful when you want to express that it's secondhand information rather than a fact you confirmed yourself. But it's not mandatory at all if you don't want to express such a nuance. The difference is simply:

- 明日は先生が来ます。
  Sensei will come tomorrow.
  <sub>(You're expressing this as a simple fact.)</sub>
- 明日は先生が来る**そうです**。
  **I heard** Sensei will come tomorrow.
  <sub>(Who you heard this from is not expressed; it may have been from the teacher themself or someone else.)</sub>